# Ruby debugging not working properly in Aptana

Tags: ruby, debugging, aptana

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and I have installed all gems needed for debugging:

`ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)`

and Aptana 3.0.10

When debugger launched through aptana, it simply prints out

`Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16, ruby-debug-base 0.11) listens on 127.0.0.1:58637`

and runs script. It won't stop on any breakpoints, even stepping isn't available. (Script terminates successfully)

my questions are:

- is this normal behavior of ruby debugger in Aptana ? ( = it is completely useless )
- would it help to use older version of ruby/Aptana to have working debugger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your 1st question:
It is not normal.   I used to use Aptana 3 (or Eclipse) in Ruby 1.8.7 on both Windows/Linux, everything works fine,  but recently i have moved from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 1.9.3... i have to re-setup everything,  it seems i only have luck in Linux,  but not windows so far.

To your 2nd question:
Yes,  if you roll back to Ruby 1.8.7 in Windows,  everything works fine in Aptana

Anyone have experience to setup ruby-debug-ide in Windows for Ruby 1.9.3/Aptana?